# I need to to use a for loop to execute println() multiple times

Tags: java

I need help writing a for loop that will print a statement multiple times based off of a user-input 'sides' variable. There also seems to be a problem with my while loop, please let me know if my syntax is off.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab6 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sides = 0;
        String poly = "ERROR!!!!!!";

        System.out.print("Enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
        sides = scan.nextInt();

        while (sides > 3 || < 12 ){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ")
        }


        if(sides == 3) {
            poly = "Triangle";
        } else if(sides == 4) {
            poly = "Quadrilaterl";
        } else if(sides == 5) {
            poly = "Pentagon";
        } else if(sides == 6) {
            poly = "Hexagon";
        } else if(sides == 7) {
            poly = "Heptagon";
        } else if(sides == 8) {
            poly = "Octagon";
        } else if(sides == 9) {
            poly = "Nonagon";
        } else if(sides == 10) {
            poly = "Decagon";
        } else if(sides == 12) {
            poly = "Dodecagon";
        } 

            for (sides >= 3 || <= 12){
                System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);//TODO:Use a 'for loop' here!
        }


}
```

Comment: *"I need help "*  What help, specifically?  Note that SO is not a 'fix/finish my code' service.  Unless you ask a specific question (& preferably just ***one*** question), this is likely to be closed.

Comment: I apologize, as I said below, I'm new to SO and thought that only asking for complete answers was frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change

```
while (sides > 3 || < 12 ){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ")
    }
```

to

```
while (sides < 3 || sides > 12) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
        sides = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Then change this

```
for (sides >= 3 || <= 12){
                System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++)
    System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);
```

That will print the statement, the number of times there are sides.

Output:

```
Enter a number from 3 to 12: 1
Please enter a number from 3 to 12: 2
Please enter a number from 3 to 12: 3
A polygon with 3 sides is called a(n) Triangle.
A polygon with 3 sides is called a(n) Triangle.
A polygon with 3 sides is called a(n) Triangle.
```

This looks like homework though... You don't want to get caught asking for answers on here...

Comment: Thank you for the help, I apologize for breaking the rules, I'm new here and thought that asking for complete solutions was frowned upon. It won't happen again!

Answer (score 0):

```
while (sides > 3 || < 12 )
```

should be

```
while (sides < 3 || sides > 12 ){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
    sides = scan.nextInt();
}
```

And this block

```
for (sides >= 3 || <= 12){
            System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);//TODO:Use a 'for loop' here!
    }
```

Should be:

```
System.out.printf("\nA polygon with"+ sides + "sides is called" + poly);
```

No need to use for loop just to print the above statement.

Comment: no, it should be while (sides < 3 || sides > 12)

Comment: @filipko I don't see a difference between your comment and the code in the answer.

Comment: @Aleks G it was edited, it was written incorrectly before.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sides = 0;
        String poly = "ERROR!!!!!!";

        System.out.print("Enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
        sides = scan.nextInt();

        while (sides < 3 || sides > 12 ){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
            sides = scan.nextInt();
        }


        if(sides == 3) {
            poly = "Triangle";
        } else if(sides == 4) {
            poly = "Quadrilaterl";
        } else if(sides == 5) {
            poly = "Pentagon";
        } else if(sides == 6) {
            poly = "Hexagon";
        } else if(sides == 7) {
            poly = "Heptagon";
        } else if(sides == 8) {
            poly = "Octagon";
        } else if(sides == 9) {
            poly = "Nonagon";
        } else if(sides == 10) {
            poly = "Decagon";
        } else if(sides == 12) {
            poly = "Dodecagon";
        } 

        if (sides >= 3 || sides <= 12){
                System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);//TODO:Use a 'for loop' here!
        }

}
```

Output

```
 Enter a number from 3 to 12: 0
 Please enter a number from 3 to 12: 1
 Please enter a number from 3 to 12: 5

 A polygon with 5 sides is called a(n) Pentagon.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use switch instead of multiple conditions. In while cycle you need also to read new input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab6 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int sides = 0;
String poly = "ERROR!!!!!!";

System.out.print("Enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
sides = scan.nextInt();

while (sides < 3 || sides > 12 ){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ")
    sides = scan.nextInt();
}

switch (sides){
    case 3:
        poly = "Triangle";
        break;
    case 4:
        poly = "Quadrilaterl";
        break;
    case 5:
        poly = "Pentagon";
        break;
    case 6:
        poly = "Hexagon";
        break;
    case 7:
        poly = "Heptagon";
        break;
    case 8:
        poly = "Octagon";
        break;
    case 9:
        poly = "Nonagon";
        break;
    case 10:
        poly = "Decagon";
        break;
    case 11:
        poly = "Elevengon";
        break;
    case 12:
        poly = "Dodecagon";
        break;
    }

    System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code. Given its quality, I assume this is homework.

```
while (sides > 3 || < 12 ){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ")
}
```

Even if you correct the condition, this will lead to an infinite loop because the conditions's value will not change once the loop is entered.

```
for (sides >= 3 || <= 12){
    System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides, poly);//TODO:Use a 'for loop' here!
}
```

Please read about for-loop syntax first. You can post specific questions then. But this looks like you wrote an `if`-statement and the corrector told you to use a `for`-loop instead. Honestly, this is not what he meant. Please try to take the time understanding how your program should work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you hardcode the answers, why not just use an array with the correct answers?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sides = 0;
        String[] polygonNames = {"invalid", "invalid", "Triangle", "Quadrilaterl", "Pentagon", "Hexagon", "Heptagon", "Octagon", "Nonagon", "Decagon", "Elevengon", "Dodecagon"};

        System.out.print("Enter a number from 3 to 12: ");
        sides = scan.nextInt();

        while (sides < 3 || sides > 12 ){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 3 to 12: ")
            sides = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.printf("\nA polygon with %d sides is called a(n) %s.", sides,     polygonNames[sides-1]);
    }
}
```